# Is there a way I can make my Player to stick to moving platforms in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a 3d platformer (with only x input) and I have animated a simple moving platform. The problem is that when the player goes onto the platform, the player just falls off when the platform starts moving again.

I have tried this code but it won't do anything...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Platform_attach : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            Player.transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            Player.transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VaZg.png)

[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te8RT.png)

Does anyone know a fix to this? It doesn't seem like it is detecting the player. I put a debug.log so I could check if it was detecting the player and it wasn't. I have another box collider on top of the original with the is trigger active. I am using my own player movement instead of the thirdpersoncharacter script. Idk if that makes a difference or not. It seems that when I removed the 2nd box collider and put the trigger on the other one my debug.log worked.

EDIT:

I made a mistake with the box colliders. I redid them and everything works now.

Comment: Make player child of platform?

Comment: Is the platform's collider a trigger or just a normal collider? In the latter case, you should be using [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and OnCollisionExit. You should also put some Debug.Log statements in your collision functions to make sure they are actually running

Comment: @BugFinder looks like that is what OP is trying to achieve, yes `Player.transform.parent = transform;`

Comment: I have tried everything... I am not sure it's the script. I put the inspector of the platform in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It works. The problem was the box colliders

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be kind of vauge because i dont know what your player's movement script looks like.

I am going to assume that whenever your player stops pressing buttons you have its velocity move towards zero, you could modify it so that it moves towards the velocity of whatever platform it is standing on instead.

Alternatively, if your player uses the rigidbody system then all you need to do is attach a kinematic rigidbody to the platform and move it with the `Rigidbody.MovePosition()` method and the physic system should do the work for you.